# Can you spread a GraphQL field?

Tags: graphql

Basically I'm trying to spread a GraphQL field so I don't have as much nesting.
For instance:

```
query {
  user(id: aasdfasdf) {
    ...address {
      street
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
{
  user: {
    street: '111 Cool Street'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From the spec:

> When querying an Object, the resulting mapping of fields are conceptually ordered in the same order in which they were encountered during query execution, excluding fragments for which the type does not apply and fields or fragments that are skipped via @skip or @include directives.

The structure of the response will always match the structure of the request. GraphQL does not inherently support any syntax to manipulate the structure of the returned response. In other words, you get what you request, and you can only request what is in the schema.

Although it's experimental, if you're using a javascript client, you could take a look at [graphql-lodash](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash). It plugs into existing clients and enables you to use custom directives to apply arbitrary transformations to your response.

Comment: great find on the graphql-lodash